# Let a macro check for references in its input

Tags: macros, ref

I want to write a macro that checks whether there are undefined references in the input and if so omits producing anything. I'd like to work it like this:

```
\begin{document}
some text...
\defref{We will see an example of this in \ref{exp:1}}
some more text
\end{document}
```

In this, the macro `defref` should check if the label `exp:1` is defined and then either print the sentence, or (if the label is not defined) do nothing.

So far, I have this:

```
\newcommand{\defref}[2]{
  \makeatletter
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{
    %do nothing
  }{
    #2
  } 
  \makeatother
}
```

which is used by giving the reference on its own as a first argument and the desired output as a second:

```
\begin{document}
some text...
\defref{exp:1}{We will see an example of this in \ref{exp:1}}
some more text
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to let the macro search for the reference before it checks whether it is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code extracts from the argument to `\defref` all `\ref{...}` parts.

Next it processes each part; if it starts with `\ref`, it uses the argument to see whether `r@#1` is defined or not and in case it isn't, sets the boolean to true.

At the end of the processing, the argument to `\defref` is typeset only if the boolean is still false.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defref}{m}
 {
  \stitch_defref:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__stitch_defref_seq
\bool_new:N \l__stitch_defref_undefined_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stitch_defref:n
 {
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { \c{ref}\{.*?\} } { #1 } \l__stitch_defref_seq
  \group_begin:
  \bool_set_false:N \l__stitch_defref_undefined_bool
  \cs_set_eq:NN \ref \__stitch_defref_check:n
  \seq_use:Nn \l__stitch_defref_seq { }
  \bool_if:NTF \l__stitch_defref_undefined_bool
   { \group_end: }
   { \group_end: #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__stitch_defref_check:n
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cF { r@#1 } { \bool_set_true:N \l__stitch_defref_undefined_bool }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{exp:2}

Some text

X\defref{We will see an example of this in \ref{exp:1}}X

X\defref{We will see an example of this in \ref{exp:2}}X

X\defref{We will see an example of this in \ref{exp:1} or in \ref{exp:2}; who knows?}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

The sequences into which the arguments are split are, in the three calls

```
The sequence \l__stitch_defref_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\ref {exp:1}}

The sequence \l__stitch_defref_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\ref {exp:2}}

The sequence \l__stitch_defref_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\ref {exp:1}}
>  {\ref {exp:2}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with some of the syntax, so I'll need some time to see if this works (right now, \ExplSyntaxOn produces the first error). But it seems to do precisely what I need, so thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I was to quick to comment. Found the package to make it work for me (xparse) and now it's perfect.Thanks!

Comment: @stitchMontgomery If you update your TeX distribution, the package is no longer required. Sorry for not having said it.